# Is there way to change style of PHP errors with CSS or inside PHP?

Tags: html, css

I need add color, background-color & more CSS properties to PHP error made before HTML, screenshot:

[image]

I tryed add some CSS for `body{}`, `html{}` or `:root{}`, but it have several problems.
When i apply some CSS for body, like `body{color: green;}` it makes whole body, including error message green, but i dont want apply styles to whole body, i need only error message. Inspect element is saying i cannot select it in css..

[image]

I was inspecting it, but because error is not in `<span>` or `<p>` with class i cannot apply styles, here is code, i tryed:

```css
:root{
 color: green;
}
html{
 color: green;
}
body{
 color: green; /* this is working, but it makes green everything in body.. */
}
```

If somone know how to add class to error, or select it in CSS please answer.
Thanks,
Oliver

Comment: Why not __fix__ errors instead?

Comment: Thoses aren't errors you want your users to see

Comment: Uh, :D but this is not only errors, it can be echos or arrays, and sometimes you (or your users) find error after some time, and its very ugly without style.. I cannot find answer on net, so i am posting question :D thx

Comment: So you should test your code and fix all erros instead of applying css styles.

Comment: "_and sometimes you (or your users) find error after some time, and its very ugly without style_" Don't show them, log them

Comment: If you want to hide errors you can use `display_errors = Off` in ur  _php.ini_ - but it is better to test your website thoroughly and fix any errors that arise

Comment: Uhh i know how to fix errors guys, i tryed to echo $string without specifying $string, i want only know how to style errors, I understand what you're trying to tell me, but i just want know how to style them.

Comment: Set `html_errors` to on and see if that gives you an HTML wrapper element around the messages that you can style; if that does not help, create a wrapper yourself by using `error_prepend_string` and `error_append_string`.

Comment: Yes, i know @NickParsons, i see it in php manual, but i dont want apply it for development and testing (btw thanks for images on my question).

Comment: @misorude thanks ^^ i'ill try

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You should use error handling function, like:

```php
    default:
        echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;
    }
```

Put it into some config, before other PHP

Comment: please add more explanation as beginners may encounter difficulties understanding your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I definitely don't suggest you do this, but there might be a way to do that. It's `set_error_handler` You can find more information about Error Handler on php.net documentation

[Error Handling Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Also you can look at here. But you need to check php.net for more examples. In case E_USER_ERROR: You can make html styles to changing errors style.

```
<?php
// error handler function
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting, so let it fall
        // through to the standard PHP error handler
        return false;
    }

    switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        echo "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
        echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
        echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
        exit(1);
        break;

    case E_USER_WARNING:
        echo "<b>My WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    case E_USER_NOTICE:
        echo "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}

// function to test the error handling
function scale_by_log($vect, $scale)
{
    if (!is_numeric($scale) || $scale <= 0) {
        trigger_error("log(x) for x <= 0 is undefined, you used: scale = $scale", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    if (!is_array($vect)) {
        trigger_error("Incorrect input vector, array of values expected", E_USER_WARNING);
        return null;
    }

    $temp = array();
    foreach($vect as $pos => $value) {
        if (!is_numeric($value)) {
            trigger_error("Value at position $pos is not a number, using 0 (zero)", E_USER_NOTICE);
            $value = 0;
        }
        $temp[$pos] = log($scale) * $value;
    }

    return $temp;
}

// set to the user defined error handler
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

Comment: @Oliver Thanks for the feedback I hope it helps.